# Crash on server Socket.io callback, using swift client library

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I've this swift code:

```
[[self.socket emitWithAck:@"setup_request" with:@[]] timingOutAfter:0 callback:^(NSArray* data) {
   NSLog(@"%@", data);
}];
```

paired with this server function:

```
client.on('setup_request', function(data, callback) {
    callback({ success:true});
});
```

but when executing it, the server crashes with this message:

```
callback({ success:true});
^
```

TypeError: callback is not a function

I'm using server version 2.0.4, and the 13.1.0 Swift client library.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix this error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That first block is Objective-C code, not Swift.

Answer (score 0):

So i guess there exist some kind of bridging in your project as clearly the first block is Objective C code, and your code is in swift.
Also `callback:^(NSArray* data)`, means the callback expects an NSArray to be passed, but in your code you are passing a closure.

Pass an NSArray instead : `callback(["success"] as? NSArray)`

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the server method interface has changed in version 2.0, now it's like:

```
client.on('setup_request', (callback) => {
    callback({success:true});
});
```